# deal with layout.phtml in zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am following this tutorial(Getting Started with Zend Framework 1.11):http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/Getting-Started-with-Zend-Framework.pdf

on page 10,zf-tutorial/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml,
the code changed from:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
$this->headTitle('Zend Framework Tutorial');
echo $this->doctype(); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
<?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h1><?php echo $this->escape($this->title); ?></h1>
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Question:

1. the output is the same, why need to change the code?
2. after I run the original code: `<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>`, in page source code: there is such output: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC....` after I run the modified code, in page source code, `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC....` supposed to appear twice, one from `$this->headMeta()...`, one from `<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>`, but it only appears one time, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 10 you have the answer to your question:

> **Common HTML code: Layouts**
>
> It also very quickly becomes obvious that there will be a lot of common HTML code in our views for the header and footer sections at least and maybe a side bar or two also. This is a very common problem and the Zend_Layout component is designed to solve this problem. **Zend_Layout allows us to move all the common header, footer and other code to a layout view script which then includes the speciﬁc view code for the action being executed.**

If you're getting duplicated results you must be including all those common header definition in both **view** and **layout**. Make sure to remove them from your **views**.